# Laravel resource api to get all entries with where clause of referenced table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.5

So, this problem is a bit complex and I don't know if I'm even on the right path to the solution anymore.
I have a few tables in a database which I want to serve as an api. I created a resource for a table which returns fields from different tables.

I have the following files:

- Http/Table.php (The model)
- Http/Resources/TableResource.php (The resource)
- Http/Controller/Tablecontroller.php (The controller)
- routes/api.php (The route file)

The resource file for the table looks like this:

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    'id' => $this->id,
    'created_at' => $this->created_at,
    'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
    'name' => $this->name,
    'website' => $this->website,
    'categories' => CategoryResource::collection($this->categories),
    'photos' => PhotoResource::collection($this->photos),
}
```

As you can see, the resource is referencing different resources and creates a single object for it.
My controller has two functions to serve all data and data with a specific id.

It looks like this:

```
public function showAll()
{
    return TableResource::collection(TableApi::all());
}

public function show($id)
{
    return new TableResource(TableApi::find($id));
}
```

And finally I made some routes:

```
Route::get('/table', 'TableController@showAll');
Route::get('/table/{id}', 'TableController@show');
```

Everything works until this point.
Now the following scenario: I want data from the table not only filtered by the id, but by the name of one of the referenced tables. So basically I want all entries where the category->name is "Test".
Is this even possible with my approach?

Comment: If `TableApi` is your model and you declared a relationship with the `Category` model, you can do something like `TableApi::where('id', $id)->whereHas('categories', function($query) {$query->where('category.name', 'Test')})->first()`.

Comment: That actually worked. Thanks. But what's missing is alle the fields from the referenced tables (categories and photos in my example). Is there a way to extend your query to get all fields? Maybe also just all fields that have a relationship with "table" in the model?

Comment: Oh, should have looked it up. The solution to my comment was just add it like that "->with('photos')"

Comment: Yup, you can include the related models using `with()`. I added a proper answer.

Comment: Please, consider accepting my answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `TableApi` is your model and you declared a relationship with the `Category` model, you can do something like:

```
TableApi::where('id', $id)->whereHas('categories', function($query) {
    $query->where('category.name', 'Test')
})->first();
```

You can include the related `Category` and `Photo` models using `with()`.

```
TableApi::where('id', $id)->whereHas('categories', function($query) {
    $query->where('category.name', 'Test')
})->with(['categories', 'photos'])->first();
```

You can read more about [querying relationships existence in the Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence).